# Swift present opens view in a weird way

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to open a new view with:

```
var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController")
self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It opens the view over the other one, how do I get it to replace the view with the other view?

[image]

Comment: You should search SO before posting a question. Your question has been asked a hundred times before.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work, just need to

`vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

before 
`self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 2):

you can change modalPresentationStyle using interface builder 
in "Presentation"

[image]